# What's the purpose of a Map/Reduce script? Pros and Cons?

Tags: netsuite, suitescript, suitescript2.0

What is the purpose for NetSuite's Map/Reduce script type?  Can't a scheduled script accomplish anything that a Map/Reduce script can do?  Is it merely a matter of an increased usage limit?  What are the pros and cons for using Map/Reduce?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Map/Reduce and Schedule script can handle large amounts of data, but Map/Reduce is best suited for situations where the data can be divided into small, independent parts. When the script is executed, a structured framework automatically creates enough jobs to process all of these parts. You as the user do not have to manage this process.

1. **Execute the job in parallel:** 
   Advantage of Map/Reduce is that these jobs can work in parallel. You choose the level of parallelism when you deploy the script.
2. **Yield automatically:**
    If a map/reduce job violates certain aspects of NetSuite governance, the Map/Reduce framework automatically causes the job to yield and its work to be rescheduled for later, without disruption to the script.

Selection from both the scripts depends on scenarios. Kindly refer the link for more detail -
https://netsuite.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/43795/kw/advantage%20of%20map%2Freduce